# Openpyxl ascii encoding error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I try to read a large xlsm file from python with following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openpyxl import load_workbook
print ("01")
wb = load_workbook("data.xlsm", data_only=True)
print ("02")
print (wb.get_sheet_names())
print ("03")
```

It returns:

```
  01
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/names/named_range.py:125: UserWarning: Discarded range with reserved name
  warnings.warn("Discarded range with reserved name")
02
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbp/Merve-Bitirme/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print (wb.get_sheet_names())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 77.2s with exit code 1]
```

How can I set openpyxl to work with utf-8 ?
When I searcher for it I found this [source code](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html) which seems to be utf-8 by default. How come I keep getting the ascii error?

Comment: This isn't an error with openpyxl but your code. Sheetnames will be unicode  objects that you'll need to encode to work with print statement.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now it works. #print(str(wb.get_sheet_names()).encode("utf-8"))